# How do I calculate an average for both positive and negative numbers displayed as h:mm:ss in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my formula:

```
J49 to 89 contain the formula =IF(I57<0,TEXT(1-I57/24/60/60,"-H:mm:ss"),TEXT(I57/24/60/60,"H:mm:ss"))
```

Which gives a result ranging from `-0:12:58` to `0:04:42`.

I would like 2 things:

Firstly for cell `B44` to contain the average from cells `J49:J89`. I've simply tried `=AVERAGE(J49:J89)` which gives `[#DIV/0!]`

And for cell `F44` to give a total sum of every cell above `0:00:00` which I've tried with `=SUMIF(J49:J85,">0")` but this just results in 0.00

What can I do here?

Comment: You're using math formulas with text values. They won't work.

Comment: In I column I have the values in seconds ranging from -778 to 282, is there a way I can use these instead?

Comment: The seconds (if numbers) will work. The seconds (as time) will not.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula

```
=IF(I57<0,TEXT(1-I57/24/60/60,"-H:mm:ss"),TEXT(I57/24/60/60,"H:mm:ss"))
```

is returning a **text** value. Text won't work in `AVERAGE` or `SUMIF` for the `sum` part.

You will need to work with **numbers** instead. If you use **time**, the negative values will error.

Once you do the calculation, you can then convert that back to text (or time (if not negative)).

Comment: Ray thank you for the advice - what formula would I need to use for the seconds (numbers) to convert it to an average in text (because it may be a negative average)? I may look like I know half of what I'm doing because of the formulas I've used so far but that's only thanks to a lot of googling1

Comment: @david Divide by 86200 (number of seconds in a day) and format to hh:mm:ss - similar to your original `=text(A1/24/60/60, "H:mm:ss"`. You may need that `if` as well if there are negatives.

Comment: Thank again Ray, but I still don't know what formula I need to put in B44 to calculate the average

Comment: @david just the `average()` with the range of seconds in it.

Comment: i've entered =AVERAGE((I49:I90)*IF(I49:I90<0,TEXT(1-I49:I90/24/60/60,"-H:mm:ss"),TEXT(I49:I90/24/60/60,"H:mm:ss"))) but it comes up with [#VALUE!]

Comment: Why are you multiplying the average by anything? Just do the `if` in another cell.